# Speeding up numpy 'between' function with dask equivalent

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dask

I'm trying to come up with a fast way of adding a new column in a DASK dataframe where the values added are based on conditions. I have been recommended an approach using numpy, but it is comparatively extremely slow.

Currently I'm loading an 11m row csv, adding several new columns whom each have formulaic calculations, and printing head and tail - in under 10 seconds.

The code that currently have for the slow/troublesome function is below. **I'd like to know if there's an equivalent approach that's native to dask**, or if the numpy query can be structured better to improve performance.

**This is the code in question**
The run time of this is 60 seconds+ - I recieve errors on default=0, so I'm not sure what the total runtime is. I am hoping the runtime can be brought down to several seconds at most.

```
import dask.dataframe as dd
import dask.multiprocessing
import dask.threaded
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np #I'd like to not use this if possible

# Dataframes implement the Pandas API
import dask.dataframe as dd

ddf["AndHeathSolRadFact"] = np.select(
    [
    (ddf[ddf['Month'].between(8, 12)]),
    (ddf[ddf['Month'].between(1, 2) & ddf['CloudCover']<30])
    ],  #list of conditions
    [1, 1],     #list of results
    default=0)      #default if no match
```

**Conversely** (as an example)**, the runtime of this is 8 seconds**. Date conversions, Datetime to month number, and a decent formula.:

```
import dask.dataframe as dd
import dask.multiprocessing
import dask.threaded
import pandas as pd

# Dataframes implement the Pandas API
import dask.dataframe as dd

from timeit import default_timer as timer
start = timer()
ddf = dd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\i5-Desktop\Downloads\Weathergrids.csv')

ddf['DateTime'] = dd.to_datetime(ddf['Date'], format='%Y-%d-%m %H:%M')
ddf['Month'] = ddf['DateTime'].dt.month

ddf['Grass_FMC'] = (97.7+4.06*ddf['RH'])/(ddf['Temperature']+6)-0.00854*ddf['RH']+3000/ddf['Curing']-30
print(ddf.head())
end = timer()
```

I'm hoping to greatly improve the performance of the first given code block where I'm assessing what the month is, and also checking cloud cover.

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: I am receiving an error with the default value. `default=0 returns ValueError: invalid entry 0 in condlist: should be boolean ndarray`

Comment: If say you have two questions here. Get the error fixed before you ask about code that you haven't been able to run.

Comment: I'd say you're correct. I stepped the code out in full, as per this gist. https://gist.github.com/anakaine/308fc1b190ba23fdf8c43bd1925c62c2 and it works as intended and completes in seconds. I'm using randomly generated values. 

When I instead use the same code with a dask data frame it takes a long time (greater than 10 minutes and fails. By instead explicitly covering the options available to the select I seem to have resolved the initial default value error. This new one has me stumped. https://gist.github.com/anakaine/bb2980369d299798cadcbe25de60a517

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer is below. It turns out I was passing a dataframe instead of a boolean array.

```
ddf["AndHeathSolRadFact"] = np.select(
    [
    (ddf['Month'].between(8,12)),
    (ddf['Month'].between(1,2) & ddf['CloudCover']>30)
    ],  #list of conditions
    [1, 1],     #list of results
    default=0)    #default if no match
```